# Is there a Python equivalent to JavaScript's requestAnimationFrame()?

Tags: python, screen

In JavaScript, there is a function [`window.requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). This function allows you to run a callback function every time the screen is about to updated.

I want to use a similar function in Python in order to see what was just drawn on the screen. currently, I am simply just running a `while` loop and using [`PIL.ImageGrab()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageGrab.html) to read the screen:

```py
while True:
  screen = PIL.ImageGrab.grab()
  if screen.getpixel((0, 0)) == (1, 2, 3):
    print("Pixel (0, 0) is rgb(1, 2, 3)")
```

I would like to replace the `while` loop with a function like JavaScript's [`window.requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). Here is an example of using `requestAnimationFrame()` in JS:

```js
function beforeFrameDrawn() {
  console.log("A frame is about to be drawn!");
  requestAnimationFrame(beforeFrameDrawn);
}
requestAnimationFrame(beforeFrameDrawn);
```

The above code is somewhat recursive. I want to use a similar function in Python, if possible. I am open to installing external libraries. I am using Python 3.11.